# How to generate dynamic IQueryable extension method

Tags: c#, linq, methods, dynamic, iqueryable

```
public static IQueryable<T> DynamicFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string Property, dynamic value) where T : class
{
    return query.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(Property) == value).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Always be careful when using `AsQueryable`. Here you seem to be mixing `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`. If you're talking with a DB you'll end up loading the tables that you're using into memory and performing the query in your app instead of doing on the SQL server and just fetching the results

Answer (score 1):

the trick here is to look at what the compiler does, i.e. compile something like:

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class C {
    public void M() {
        var query = Data.Where(x => x.Bar == "abc");
    }
    System.Linq.IQueryable<Foo> Data;
    class Foo {
        public string Bar {get;set;}
    }
}
```

and see what it does; if we [look in sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgDIEsB2BHA3AWACgioBmBAJjgGE4BvIuJhcqAFjgFkAKASnsbMhANwCGAJzjYArgFNxATzgBeOABFRAF1HIA6gAt5s7gA8VAPjgnkAIQkrVAIlEAjAMaPeBQkIC+gpiQ0LGxkAEkARTlFVwAbWQAeADEAexTLDW1vISgqVJSBHyFmMgREeDtJOgBzWU1cAGc63H8iplbWoA===), we see:

```cs
public void M()
{
    IQueryable<Foo> data = Data;
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");
    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle((RuntimeMethodHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/)), Expression.Constant("abc", typeof(string)));
    ParameterExpression[] obj = new ParameterExpression[1];
    obj[0] = parameterExpression;
    IQueryable<Foo> queryable = Queryable.Where(data, Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(body, obj));
}
```

and we can infer  that you want something similar, i.e.

```cs
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var body = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(p, Property),
    Expression.Constant((object)value)
);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
return query.Where(lambda);
```